# deny access to default page of web but allow access beneath

Tags: 2010, access

I have a site in SharePoint 2010 (call it  www.thesite.com) containing several subsites containing various reports arranged by category -  www.thesite.com/cat-a,  www.thesite.com/cat-b, etc..

and one additional sub site site containing the frameset of a custom search page, www.thesite.com/custsearch. The menu frame calls the search page for the whole site up in /search.

The user has the address of the custom searchpage, www.thesite.com/custsearch/custsearch.aspx.

But the way the web is currently set up, there's nothing stopping them from manually erasing part of the URL and getting to www.thesite.com/ While technically there's nothing they can do there to cause trouble as they'd only be set up with rad privileges, I'd still rather not let them get there.

Is there a way to restrict the users' access to the default page, while still give them access to the site beneath?

I tried loading the web in a frameset to hide the address a bit, but the authorization program I'm using is smart enough to recognize it's in a frameset, assume something weasely is bring tried, and break out of it.

A more low-tech solution might be to send the user to a staging page that launches a new browser window that has no URL visible, but if I can handle it in SP it'd be simpler, and less confusing for the user, especially if they have pop-ups turned off or the like.

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about two site collections here

1. www.thesite.com
2. www.thesite.com/custsearch

Both site collections have their unique permission groups. In order to restrict the user to access www.thesite.com, remove 'NT Authority' group if you have added there and make sure only required users are added in the site collection.

At max you can give them Read access. In this way they would be able to access the site but will not be able to change anything

Comment: Alas, it's not even that easy - I only want to restrict their access to the default.aspx page itself. They need access to the search pages under the root web.

Hm...can I rename the default pages without breaking anything?

Comment: How will renaming the default page resolve your problem? It wont break anything... You just have to make sure you set the new renamed URL as the lading page.